# How to find the smallest of an array within VBA, not in an excel range

Tags: excel, vba

Basic idea here is roll 4 d6, drop the lowest.

```
For lngPosition = LBound(strAttributes) To UBound(strAttributes)

        i = 0
        For shortPosition = LBound(intRoll) To UBound(intRoll)
           intRoll(shortPosition) = Int((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
           i = intRoll(shortPosition) + i
        Next shortPosition

        i = {i - smallest intRoll()}

        strAttributes(lngPosition) = i

    Next lngPosition
```

I've found a lot of info on how to find the lowest value in a range in excel, by adding `.Small` after defining the range, but I don't think that works here. It may be that I'm off by miles on how to accomplish this, but I'm so fresh that I really don't know.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your array is a one-dimensional array, you can still use the worksheetfunction class, like:

```
Dim myArray
myArray = Array(5, 3, 103, 99, -14, 12)

Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Small(myArray, 1)
```

If your array is multi-dimensional, then you will need to use brute force iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how you can achieve it :

```
Sub test()
    Dim a(10), i&
    For i = 0 To 10
       a(i) = i
    Next
    MsgBox "Min: " & WorksheetFunction.Min(a) & Chr(10) & _
            "Avg: " & WorksheetFunction.Average(a) & Chr(10) & _
            "Max: " & WorksheetFunction.Max(a)
End Sub
```